# Congratulations to the elected moderators of 2011!

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

**According to [the election page](https://superuser.com/election), the new moderators have been picked:**

[image: Sathya]
[image: studiohack]
[image: DMA57361]

Congratulations!

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  We will do our best to prove ourselves worthy of the Super User community!

Comment: I'm going to vote to close as "subjective and argumentative" j/k :P Congrats guys!

Comment: Congrats to the new mods!

Comment: @WesleyWerner  thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congrats. You will all help make Super User a much better place.  Use your ♦ abilities wisely and ask questions to the other moderators, which I am sure you will have.  Welcome to the team!

Oh, and withhold the temptation to delete or suspend Super User #1: https://superuser.com/users/1  That might not end well for you. ;)

Comment: now that's a smart idea... suspend user#1

Comment: but, but...now that you've suggested it you've made it sooo much harder to resist...like a big red "DO NOT PRESS" button :P

Comment: @DMA57361 [there you go](http://i.imgur.com/4mkVL.png)

Comment: @Sathya ... so shiny... can't resist...

Answer (score 1):

Well done to the new mods. Now get back to work.